# Android ScrollView inside the TabHost

Tags: android

I am creating the TabHost activity and taking a ListView in the TabHost. The ListView is bydefault scroll vertically wihtin TabHost. 
Now i want to take ScrollView within the TabHost. Is it possible to do like that, because i have tried but it's not working.
Kindly help me out.
 please provide me any tutorial link related to this.

With Thanks
Vikash

Comment: do you want to have a listView inside a ScrollView inside a tabHost?

Comment: Show some code - what did you try and so we can tell you why it's not working.

Comment: yes, sounds like an interface - those are not hard to do - show some code

Comment: Please clear your question little more.It is hard to understand how and where you want a scrollview.because listview would always be scrollable.Then why do you need another scrollview inside tab activity?

Answer (score 2):

you can use a scrollView within TabHost, But you need to take horizontal scrollView as main tag within that TabHost.

```
 <HorizontalScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
```